# compare varchar value to sysdate

Tags: datetime, oracle11g

I got  timeEnd VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)

```
timeEnd                          value
2013-11-15 00:52:46.000          13NC1356
2013-11-08 01:18:15.000          13NC1241
2013-11-14 14:41:29.000          13NC1241
2013-11-05 06:40:48.000          13CP1183
2013-10-08 23:30:33.000          13CP1186
2013-11-09 01:08:39.000          13CP1186
```

I need to compare these `dates` with `sysdate` and if `max(timeEnd)` for unique `value` is 24 hours  old I need to display data (for now).

So to keep it simple for now, I need to somehow convert `timeEnd` `string` values in the format `sysdate` is. 
I tried many things, they all are failing for now...

I will keep trying, just thought someone out there knows how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean convert to DATE data type?  SYSDATE is a function that returns the current database time.  Your timeEnd string looks like a TIMESTAMP data type.  If you want to
convert it to a TIMESTAMP (example):

```
select to_timestamp(timeEnd,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

If you want to convert to a DATE, you need to remove the fractional seconds:

```
select to_date(substr(timeEnd,1,19),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

See the Oracle [Formatting options](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm) for all the details.

You also may want to question why you are storing a date/time as a string.  Use the correct native data type to avoid a littany of issues.  You will be happier in the long-run.